# Django - How to filter down duplicates in a query?

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a query in Django that is resulting in unique rows but some contain common values in various fields.  I want to consolidate those rows with the common values.
Example:
    Assume each row returns an *id, library, book title, author,* and *publication date*.
    I only want to know only about the book title, author and publication date.  Additionally, I would like to know about *1 and only one library* where it can be found.  How so using Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
Books.objects.all().only('title', 'author', 'date').extra(where=['library IS NOT NULL']).distinct()
```

Comment: I am not seeing results from it.  What is the purpose of `.extra(where=['library IS NOT NULL'])` ?

Comment: And, apparently, even though Django is explicitly told title, author and date -- it is including primary keys also!

Comment: You could use .filter(...).values('title', 'author', 'date').distinct()
I have not tried this, tell me if its not working and I will do it tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your data model is incomplete.  It sounds like you're trying to find a library which is in possession of a particular book.  In the case where there are many libraries in possession of said book, you'll need some discriminating criteria in order to get the database to filter the list of libraries down to one and only one.  Otherwise, if you *really* don't care, consider using the `limit` method.

```
myquery.limit(1)
```

Comment: Myquery retrieves a large number of rows that _could possibly_ include duplicate _book title, author, and publication date_ .  I think that limit() wouldn't work there.